# How to convert csv into time series in R with multiple variables?

Tags: r, time-series

I need your help in converting my csv into time series in R. The csv file contains multiple variables as well as the date column -year.
The data looks like this:

```
head(df)
  year region        x1         x2       x3 x4         x5     x6 x7 x8 x9
1 1960  World  9420.523 3031437768 1.37e+12  0 0.00082925 0.8292  0  0  0
2 1961  World  9460.860 3072481005 1.43e+12  0 0.00079847 0.7985  0  0  0
3 1962  World  9849.562 3125456669 1.53e+12  0 0.00078753 0.7875  0  0  0
4 1963  World 10388.611 3190564033 1.65e+12  0 0.00078845 0.7884  0  0  0
5 1964  World 10982.665 3256064763 1.81e+12  0 0.00078109 0.7811  0  0  0
6 1965  World 11477.710 3322973362 1.97e+12  0 0.00077360 0.7736  0  0  0
      x10      x11       x12
1 1370000 145.4272 0.1454272
2 1430000 151.1490 0.1511491
3 1530000 155.3369 0.1553369
4 1650000 158.8278 0.1588278
5 1810000 164.8052 0.1648052
6 1970000 171.6370 0.1716370
>
```

I've tried different libraries - zoo, xts and none is working properly.

```
> ts<- ts(data, start=1960)
> 
> 
> autoplot(ts)
```

autoplot produces a plot of all variables. when I try

```
autoplot(ts$x1)

Error in ts$x1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
>
```

Tried with tsibble the problem is the same.
The I tried with zoo library:

```
library (zoo)
> 
> df <- read.csv("data.csv", sep=",")
> ts_series <- as.ts(read.zoo(df, FUN = as.yearmon))
> 
> model <- lm(x1 ~ x3, data=ts_series)
Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
> print(model)
```

There is a mistake somewhere. when I use autoplot(ts_series) all variables are plotted, I've tried to use ts_series$x1 or ts_series["x1"], apparently both are incorrect.

I would like to be able to autoplot after the csv is converted into time series, as follows:
autoplot (ts_series, x1) where the first term "ts_series" is calling the whole time series and the second term is the specific variable "x1". also the time series can be used for other task such as simple regression.

Comment: All the columns must be numeric.

Comment: I've deleted the column with strings, but now when I do autoplot I cannot plot two variables in one plot just one variable is allowed: autoplot (x1, x2) I get the error object "x2" is not found.

Comment: You can only pass one zoo object but that zoo object can have any number of columns.  Please read `?autoplot.zoo`